# Why is apache2 using the default vhost if I request a domain that is the same as the servers hostname, and how can I prevent it?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, virtualhost, hostname

I have a website that I want to be able to reach using `http://mydomain.com` as well as `http://www.mydomain.com`

Recently I configured my servers `hostname` to `mydomain.com`

I have installed apache2 in default from ubuntu 12.04 repositories and configured the following configuration file under `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mydomain.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.de
        ServerAlias     www.mydomain.de
        DocumentRoot /home/mydomain/public
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /home/mydomain/public>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Now If I request `http://www.mydomain.com` everything works, but if I request `http://www.mydomain.com` I get the default "it works" apache welcome page.

If I prefix my config file in a way that it gets listed even before the `000-default` vhost, so it looks like this:

```
ls -lha /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul  6 18:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4.0K Oct  5  2012 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Jul  6 18:45 000-0mydomain -> /home/mydomain/apache2.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Jul  6 18:29 000-default -> ../sites-available/default
```

it does work.

However I do not know whether this is a good idea or why this occurs in the first place. It also works when the server hostname does not correspond to the domain name!

I think apache is somehow unable to distinguish between requests without host header and requests whith the host header that is the same as the hostname...

So what can I do about this? How can I properly do this?

I think adjusting the name so my vhost ocmes eben before the default which is not named `000-default` just to annoy people is not a good idea...

Comment: Do you still need the default file enabled at all?

Comment: @Shane Madden no, i dont... not really... but i dont know about the future. i would like to set this up as clean and compatible as possible

Answer (score 0):

When you type `hostname -f`, is that your domain as well? I think the default vhost is responding to the machine domain name. My advice would be to set a different host name for the machine, because the name you use to administer it should be different from the website that runs on it. Otherwise, you won't be able to do things like give the website a temporary different address and display a maintenance message.

If you don't want to do that, you can configure a dummy ServerName in 000-default.

Comment: yes, hostname -f is also that domain. i configured the machines hostname to the same domain for reasons when sending email. those problems i had have been completely solved and this new one arose. also modifying the default vhost is not really what i want. i prefer having all my stuff in one config file that i symlink and have in a versionized folder.

Comment: I mean, just having the 'it works' vhost's servername be www.dummy.com. That should fix it.